# Normalize Bing redirect URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$link = preg_replace("=","$1",$link);
```

I'd like to just keep the original URL but this code not work for this URL below!

```
http://www.bing.com/news/apiclick.aspx?ref=FexRss&amp;aid=&amp;tid=5BE65E4DC2EF4C818571BA346120C300&amp;url=http%3a%2f%2fsiouxcityjournal.com%2fmobile%2farticle_584d875c-91ec-53ef-ae51-0aeb0fb7c8d3.html&amp;c=9ul_XzxSMow9YJ2trisClb6T2Kc7YBWrzDj5tvyCAno&amp;mkt=en-us
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is no `$1` and `"="` is also not a correct regex. In PHP you use delimiters like `'/=/'`

Comment: I need to know what you're trying to do here using `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

You  need this:

```
<?php

$bingUrl = "http://www.bing.com/news/apiclick.aspx?ref=FexRss&amp;aid=&amp;tid=5BE65E4DC2EF4C818571BA346120C300&amp;url=http%3a%2f%2fsiouxcityjournal.com%2fmobile%2farticle_584d875c-91ec-53ef-ae51-0aeb0fb7c8d3.html&amp;c=9ul_XzxSMow9YJ2trisClb6T2Kc7YBWrzDj5tvyCAno&amp;mkt=en-us";

preg_match_all('/url=(.*?)&/i', $bingUrl, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$newUrl = rawurldecode($match[1][0]);
echo $newUrl;
//http://siouxcityjournal.com/mobile/article_584d875c-91ec-53ef-ae51-0aeb0fb7c8d3.html
```

---

**DEMO:**
http://ideone.com/yJHwrD

---

**REFERENCES:**

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)
[rawurldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)